# Перебивал манеру письма?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, синонимы

В рассказе [«Последний придворный поэт»](https://gumilev.ru/prose/4/) Н. Гумилёв пишет:

> Его слуга целый день бегал по книжным магазинам, покупая для него стихи других поэтов, «городских», как прежде он их называл с презрительной усмешкой. И два месяца в кабинете с забытыми ныне табакерками шла напряженная и тайная работа. Придворный поэт учился у своих младших братьев и перебивал манеру письма.

Что такое «перебивать манеру»? Смысл в целом улавливается, но предложить синоним не берусь.

Answer (score 2):

***Перебивать манеру письма*** — это, вероятно, с одной стороны, изучать и перенимать, а с другой —  создавать нечто новое на этой основе.

Похоже на **авторскую лексику**, потому что  у этого слова нет подобного значения, а приставка ПЕРЕ обозначает переделывать заново, изменять. Нет этого значения и в словаре у Даля.

Тогда ***перебивать*** — это переделывать на свой лад, внося существенные изменения и улучшения.  Такой смысл следует из содержания рассказа. Соответственно, подобрать синоним для авторского слова довольно-таки сложно.